# Error when I try to calculate the normalization on Jupyter notebook (with '-' and df)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I'm just discovering pandas, I tried to google the error but I found nothing.
When I try to calculate this: `X = (X - X.min()) / (X.max() - X.min())` knowing that (`X = titanic[['sex','age','fare','class','embark_town','alone']].copy())`
I get this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ2FY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBv2q.png)

Please any suggestions to correct it ?

Answer (score 0):

At least the error is telling you that you can not use "-" operator to the boolean type of operators. So it seems that X.min() equals to True or False.

Comment: When I print X or X.min() or X.max() it it's not bool but a df ..

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize numerical features only (like fare in the Titanic dataset).